# VPN connected but no access to anything

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, pptp

I have a problem with the VPN server on 2008R2. I can successfully connect to the VPN server but i cannot map any drives either by IP or by name. I can ping hosts by ip but not the name. In addition I can access shares and RDP only to the VPN server but not to any others.

What could be the problem? Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Symantec Endpoint Protection was blocking traffic.